# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent on post request, why?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Any time I added validation from my schema and try to make a post request I get the following error message:

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

```
var PlayerSchema   = new Schema({
    firstName:  { type: String, require: true, required: 'First Name is required' },
    lastName:   { type: String, require: true, required: 'Last Name is required' },
    nickName:   { type: String, trim: true },
    mentor:     { type: String, trim: true },
    clubName:   { type: String, trim: true },
    created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    updated_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },

    email: {
        type:   String,
        trim:   true,
        unique: true,
        required: 'Email address is required',
        validate: [validateEmail, 'Please fill a valid email address'],
        match: [/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/, 'Please fill a valid email address']
    },
    phoneNumber: { 
      type:     String, 
      unique:   true, 
      required: 'Phone Number is required',

    }
});
```

Comment: This error pops up whenever response is sent twice for one request, you can check your post request for the same where you are sending response

Comment: i am using post man to send the request

Comment: Your error is caused by how you're handling HTTP requests, and you're not posting any code related to that.

Comment: can you show me an example of what you are talking of am a newbies in MEAN STACK

Comment: They mean this has nothing to do with mongodb or mongoose and everything to do with the express routing you are using (assuming you are using that since you said MEAN stack).

Comment: It's likely an async issue. You're probably executing a callback in an `if` statement without returning it.

Comment: It sounds like nagging, but please try to make a concise question or request that is actionable so the community can be more useful to you, and future users.